# SQL Server error in conversion of date from string

Tags: sql, sql-server

`NPD.CreatedOn` is defined as a `datetime` datatype column (in SQL Server).

```
SELECT * 
FROM NPDMaster NPD 
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), NPD.CreatedOn, 126), CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 126)) <= 6
```

I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

What can I try to resolve it?

Comment: For example?...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert the `datetime` values to text. `DATEDIFF()` expects `datetime` values as second and third [argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments):

```
SELECT * 
FROM NPDMaster NPD    
WHERE DATEDIFF(month, NPD.CreatedOn, GETDATE()) <= 6
```

The actual reason for the error (as is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks)), is that *...DATEDIFF implicitly casts string literals as a datetime2 type*.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use things like `DATEDIFF` in the `WHERE` on your columns, such queries aren't SARGable and thus can (will) perform poorly. If you want rows where the date is on or after the start of the month 6 months ago then do the date logic on `GETDATE()`/`SYSDATETIME()`/etc:

SQL Server doesn't have a "start of month" function, but you can use `EOMONTH` and then add a day:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.NPDMaster NPD
WHERE NPD.CreatedOn >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-7));
```